# Show hyperlink after javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to edit this piece of code to show a hyperlink when the countdown ends.

I can not seem to make it work though. Could anyone help me?

```
<html>
    <p id="week1"></p>

<script>
var countDownDate1 = new Date("Jul 10, 2020 12:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate1 - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("week1").innerHTML = "Nog " + days + " dagen, " + hours + " uur, "
  + minutes + " minuten en " + seconds + " seconden.";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("week1").innerHTML = "HOW TO GET A HYPERLINK HERE";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Just write HTML hyperlink code instead!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One of the key sections has the header "Search, and research...".

Answer (score 1):

*sigh*

```html
<html>
    <p id="week1"></p>

<script>
var countDownDate1 = new Date("Jul 10, 2020 12:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate1 - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("week1").innerHTML = "Nog " + days + " dagen, " + hours + " uur, "
  + minutes + " minuten en " + seconds + " seconden.";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("week1").innerHTML = "<a href='https://insert.url.here/'>Hyperlink text</a>";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```